# Replace multiple jQuery .on() with one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic plugin with various functions and I'm triggering those functions with click events.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="el" id="el1">
        <a href="#" class="edit-el">Edit</el>
        <a href="#" class="delete-el">Delete</el>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
// Edit an el
$('.container').on('click', '.edit-el', function(e){
    var elId = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.el')[0];
    plugin.editEl(elId);
});
// Delete an el
$('.container').on('click', '.delete-el', function(e){
    var elId = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.el')[0];
    plugin.deleteEl(elId);
});
```

**Question**: Is it possible to optimize this code so I don't have two click event listeners? This should give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve (*Not working*):

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e){
    var control = e.currentTarget;
    if ( control == '.edit-el') {
        plugin.editEl(elId);
    }
    if ( control == '.delete-el') {
        plugin.deleteEl(elId);
    }
});
```

Comment: I will  stick with multiple separate event handler due to Separation of concern principle. Its simple to use `this` instead of `e.currentTarget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to answer this question with optimised code, simply because I think the code you have *is* already optimal. The reason is down to a simple phrase - separation of concerns. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns):

> In computer science, separation of concerns (SoC) is a design principle for separating a computer program into distinct sections, such that each section addresses a separate concern.

At present, you have two completely separate areas of functionality:

- An event handler that manages editing of an element
- An event handler that manages deletion of an element

The "benefit" you would get from having both under the same handler is that your code will be slightly shorter. In return, you'd be combining two completely distinct functions into a single procedure and impacting on both readability and maintainability.

Comment: I think you're right. Reason being, if I add another span for an icon to the anchor link, e.currentTarget would be incorrect. Don't think there's a solid workaround to that apart from my current version of code so I'm going to stick with that. Thanks!

Comment: Disagree, single event handler is correct approach in this case. Both edit and delete, or whatever are just links clicking on which then further dispatches correct action. So nothing is mixed here and editing and deleting are still perfectly separated on `plugin.<actionName>` level. Having separate event handlers in this case – is wrong and less optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Get the target element an compare it's `href`

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e){
    var control = $(e.target);
    if ( control.hasClass('edit-el')) {
        plugin.editEl(elId);
    }
    else if ( control.hasClass('delete-el')) {
        plugin.deleteEl(elId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e){
    var control = $(e.target);
    if ( control.is('.edit-el')) {
        plugin.editEl(elId);
    }
    else if ( control.is('.delete-el')) {
        plugin.deleteEl(elId);
    }
});
```

However I would recommend you to persist with your existing approach due to [separation of concerns](http://deviq.com/separation-of-concerns/) principle